# How to set spawnpoint?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I don't know the command to set our spawn in Minecraft 1.12.1.

Is it `/set spawn`? I honestly can't figure it out.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: Can you please mark the given answer as accepted? Otherwise this question looks like it's unanswered and people might come here to answer it, just to find that it was already done.

Comment: @Fabian Users like the OP normally just come onto the site to ask a question once and never return. Don't expect much from them.

Comment: I often write different wordings of this question. If it gets read and the answer gets accepted, that's good, if not, it's just another part that can slightly annoy someone who's already slightly annoyed by the fact that there is no accepted answer (like me).

Answer (score 6):

It’s `/spawnpoint` per player or `/setworldspawn` for the world.

**References:**

1. https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/setworldspawn
2. https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/spawnpoint
3. https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands

Answer (score 1):

If it is a map or a server do `/setworldspawn <cordinates>` to set where you first spawn in when you haven't played yet. Like this:
`/setworldspawn 0 0 0`.

If it is just where you spawn when you die, do `/setspawn <cordinates>`. Like this: `/setspawn 0 0 0`.

Or you can just do `/time` to set night and use a bed.

Comment: Except for the bed, this doesn't add anything to the existing answer. And the bed is not really useful when you can just do `/spawnpoint`.